# is there a C++ equivalent to SQL DENSE_RANK() window function?

Tags: c++, sql, dense-rank, c++23

Let's say you have a table

```
Customer | Product
Dave     | Sneakers
Martin   | Tooth Brush
Andrew   | Shirt
Dave     | Tooth Brush
```

In SQL, you can do

```
SELECT Customer, Product, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Customer) AS customer_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Product) AS product_id

Customer | Product      | customer_id | product_id
Dave     | Sneakers     |  2          | 2
Martin   | Tooth Brush  |  3          | 3
Andrew   | Shirt        |  1          | 1
Dave     | Tooth Brush  |  2          | 3
```

Which can be usefull if you want to split the data into three tables

```
Customer (customer_id, customer_name)
Product (product_id, product_name)
Customer_Product(customer_id, product_id)
```

Is there a function in C++ that comes close to what is achieved with DENSE_RANK() in SQL ?

If a range over a structure, with a field for every column in C++ can be seen as an equivalent of a table in SQL.

With hindsight, after the question has been closed, here is the answer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <ranges>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const vector<int> v = {7,9,9,7};
    const auto dense_rank = views::zip(v | ranges::to<set>(),views::iota(0)) | ranges::to<unordered_map>() ;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it requires implicit conversion from tuple to pair, so it does not compile with g++14 at the moment.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "table" in C++. Let's start with that. So how do you expect for there be some "function" that "comes close" to this SQL, when C++ is not a database engine, and it does not have anything like tables, or columns? You obviously have some kind of a C++ data structure in mind that represents a table, unfortunately we're not mind readers, and have no idea what it is, or how the desired function might work.

Comment: a range in C++ is like a table in SQL

Comment: So is a pair of iterators. I wouldn't want to assume that it's ranges, spend time writing up an elaborate answer, only to get "oh, sorry, I just have a pointer to an array and an array size, or a vector", and then end up wasting a lot of time.

Comment: And if it's ranges, the next question would be: a range of ***what*** exactly? A structure, with a field for every column? A vector of values, one value for every column? A range of ranges? We're still not mind readers.

Comment: A structure with a field for every column

Comment: So you simply want the index of the iterator, where the data is already sorted? `std::distance(first_iterator, iterator)` gives you this. But not very efficient if your iterators do not meet the `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` requirement. Maybe you need https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view, but thats c++23.

Comment: @Aedoro the data probably isn't sorted. The example SQL has two different columns being `ORDER BY`ed

Comment: The SQL Engine does not have a magic function, either, that gives the rank, for each row. The SQL Engine does exactly what anyone expects it to do, here: a preliminary pass over all the rows, extracting unique values in the specified column, sorting it, creating a lookup of each value's rank, then making a final pass over the rows, retrieving each value's rank from the temporary lookup table. This will be done the same way in C++. There is no range function that does it automatically. There are very, very few magic buttons in C++ that do everything, once pushed. This isn't one of them.

Comment: Can we assume the range satisfies `std::ranges::random_access_range`?

Comment: yes doesn't seem too restrictive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a function in `std` like that. The range algorithms that are even close have a prerequisite that the input range be sorted in the desired order, and there isn't a `sorted_view` to get the desired orders from your data.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways you can do this.
Here is a start with some range-based functions.

```cpp
auto sorted_references(std::ranges::view auto range, const auto cmp)
{
    using T = std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(range)>;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> index { range.begin(), range.end() };
    std::ranges::sort(index, [&](auto l, auto r) {
        return cmp(l.get(), r.get());
    });
    return index;
}

void dense_rank(std::ranges::view auto range, const auto cmp, const auto output)
{
    auto index = sorted_references(range, cmp);

    size_t rank = 0;

    output(index.front().get(), rank);

    for (auto it1 = index.begin(), it2 = std::next(it1), end = index.end(); it2 != end; ++it1, ++it2)
    {
        output(it2->get(), cmp(it1->get(), it2->get()) ? ++rank : rank);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> data{ "b", "b", "d", "a", "c" };

    dense_rank(data | std::views::all,
        std::less<>(),
        [](auto& value, size_t rank)
    {
        std::cout << value << ": " << rank << std::endl;
    });
}
```

```
a: 0
b: 1
b: 1
c: 2
d: 3
```

Comment: you could use `std::vector`s range constructor: `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>index(std::from_range, range);` instead of the for loop

Comment: @0xbachmann I updated it to using the the non-c++23 fix to remove the loop. Your suggestion is of course good if you do have c++23. Also removes the (lack of) `reserve()` issue (i assume).